# Where is the <title> set in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, title

I am searching for the exact location in which file, where the `<title>` tag is being filled. Could anyone point me there?

I've searched all the sites I could find but I could not find it :(

Comment: Can you provide more information on the version of wordpress you're using and any themes you have installed?

Answer (score 1):

well there are many title tags in the wordpress theme but i think what you are looking for is located in : `wp-content/themes/theme_name/header.php`

```
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally the title tag is in the header.php

```
/wp-content/themes/(your theme name here)/header.php
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<title>` tag can be found in the header.php file of a theme's base directory.

This generally calls the wp_title function, which according to the wordpress documentation, can be found in wp-includes>general-template.php

[Wordpress Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/)

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are true for WordPress versions earlier than 4.1. There is actually a much easier, much more dynamic way of adding the title tag into WordPress that doesn't require hardcoding `<title>`.

If you have WordPress version 4.1 or later, you might want to check your functions file for: `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );`

If that's in there, the title tag is being generated by WordPress.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Title_Tag